# Why doesn't tizen studio connect to my S3 watch

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

What are the magic words one has to utter to get Tizen Studio to connect to S3 watch?

I have S3 watch that is connected to my wifi network. I can ping that device just fine. I have made sure debug option is turned on the watch.

I have been able to connect to this S3 watch multiple time. But anytime I change my wifi network (between work and office) I literally have to pray that Tizen studio would connect to S3 watch.

Is there a reliable way to connect with S3 watch from Tizen Studio?

If there way to connect to Samsung S3 watch over USB?

Unfortunately my employer has decided to develop app for Samsung Gear S3, but connecting to watch from Tizen Studio has been frustrating experience so say the least....

Answer (score 15):

**Tested Solution**

Hi everyone, after some tedious testing I've found a way to consistently get your Watch to connect to your PC, I've tested these steps on two devices and they are as follows:

1. Enable developer mode (Settings > About Watch > Software > Tap on Software Version 5 times)
2. Enable debugging (Settings > About Watch > Debugging)
3. Switch wifi to always on (Settings > Connections > WiFi) and connect to the network your PC is on.
4. Restart your Watch.
5. Turn on your display and **Leave the watch face** by navigating to another widget (I used the contacts widget).
6. Get the IP of your watch (Settings > Connections > WiFi > WiFi Networks > [Your WiFi SSID] > IP Adress)
7. Now connect to your Watch with either the Tizen Studio Device Manager (Tools > Device Manager > Add) or via the CLI using the command `sdb connect x.x.x.x`

I've tested this method with success two times on two PC's with both Intel & AMD CPUs, the main takeaway is that the Watch seems to hate prompting the user for permissions on the Watch Face screen, and simply navigating off it will get things working correctly.

Comment: I would like to upvote your answer 10 TIMES OVER, just for step 5!!!! Nobody ever mentions that "little" detail! Now it seems to work, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really a lifesaver

Answer (score 11):

I tried all steps above and was quite desperate already, then I tried to reboot my device and it did it. *Facepalm*. After the reboot and another attempt to connect I was prompted to accept a certificate on the gear watch and that was it.

So my advice, **just reboot your (gear) device** if you cant connect it might save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

Even I faced the same issue. If anybody unable to connect remote device even in same network try below steps:

1. Unpair the watch (Turn off Bluetooth connectivity)
2. **Turn Off** the watch
3. Turn it On
4. Make sure both PC/Mac and watch connected to same network
5. find out IP address of watch
6. Connect using remote device dialog

Hopefully this time you will get a prompt in watch to accept connection.
Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

as far as I know S2 and S3 can only connect through WiFi.

WiFi connection can be unstable sometimes.

Instead of connecting using Tizen studio I use this script each time it disconnects, it's faster

```
sdb connect "device_ip":26101
```

Replace "device_ip" with the IP of your device, without quotes.

After running that command, the device will appear in the Connection Explorer of Tizen Studio

Comment: Done that but it still doesn't work. As I said in original message I can see the device with <ip-address> I can ping it but sdb connect ip-address:26101 doesn't always connect.

Comment: Are you connected with Bluetooth to your smartphone?
When the watch is connected using bluetooth it looses the wifi connection.
Recently the S2 received an update that came with an option in the Wifi settings to keep wifi always on. Not sure if S3 has that option also.

Comment: Same issue, I think it's a fundamental issue with sdb and latest Mac versions

Answer (score 2):

I've run into that problem a few times. A few things to check and do.

Is debug mode enabled? Remember that if you pair the watch with a different phone that debug mode will be turned off.

If WiFi on? You will want to go into settings and set the WiFi to "Always On." Keep the watch on a charging cradle between debug sessions. The battery will drain much faster.

Before starting Tizen Studio try connecting from the command line. Note, pay attention to the watches screen when you do this! If the watch is pin locked or pattern locked you need to unlock it before continuing.  You will get prompted to accept an RSA key the first time you try and if you are not watching the key won't be accepted and the connection *will* fail! As mentioned above use

sdb connect {ip address}

When I do this the command usually reports failure the first time around but success the second time. After it's connected start Tizen Studio.  While this wasn't part of your question remember that if this is your first time deploying to the watch or if the watch has since been reset that you will need to take care of getting a development certificate installed on the watch.

Answer (score 2):

I know the S3 does have an option to keep the wi-fi on.
 I also noticed that sometimes just because it's on the wi-fi and pingable it doesn't always connect.

I did try to restart my watch and that didn't seem to affect it.  what did work for me, was I noticed in the ADB there was commands to kill server and start server.  I used those then then tried again to connect from the command line,  it gave me an error about being unauthorized. which was a different error then i was getting before.  So I toggled the debug settings off then back on in my watch and tried connecting again from the command line.  And that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Liam Harrison solution with extra step:

"

**Tested Solution**

Hi everyone, after some tedious testing I've found a way to consistently get your Watch to connect to your PC, I've tested these steps on two devices and they are as follows:

1. Enable developer mode (Settings > About Watch > Software > Tap on Software Version 5 times)
2. Enable debugging (Settings > About Watch > Debugging)
3. Switch wifi to always on (Settings > Connections > WiFi) and connect to the network your PC is on.
4. Restart your Watch.
5. Turn on your display and **Leave the watch face** by navigating to another widget (I used the contacts widget).
6. Get the IP of your watch (Settings > Connections > WiFi > WiFi Networks > [Your WiFi SSID] > IP Adress)
7. Now connect to your Watch with either the Tizen Studio Device Manager (Tools > Device Manager > Add) or via the CLI using the command `sdb connect x.x.x.x`

I've tested this method with success two times on two PC's with both Intel & AMD CPUs, the main takeaway is that the Watch seems to hate prompting the user for permissions on the Watch Face screen, and simply navigating off it will get things working correctly.

"

Extra step: ensure Tizen Studio is not running if connecting from `sdb` cli as Tizen Studio appears to lock the connection and cli returns message:

```
connecting to ...:26101
failed to connect to ...:26101
```

Once I quick Tizen Studio the watch connected. Upon start of Tizen Studio the watch is available from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If what has been suggested hasn't worked for you, just make sure your watch is using the same IP address each time it connects to a new network.  If not, update the IP address in the Remote Device Manager to reflect the current address of the device each time you connect.  Also, bluetooth should be off to make sure it isn't already connected to a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my router, It would be nice to use station to plug in a reliable usb link

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. On the watch, open settings - connections - WiFi - Click on "always
   on"
2. Connect to your WiFi.
3. Once again, open settings - connections - WiFi's - Click on your WiFi - Navigate to the bottom and write down your watches IP-address.
4. Download + Install [Tizen Studio 3.2 with CLI(command line interface) installer](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download)
5. On windows, open cmd and navigate: to C:\tizen-studio\tools and type:

> sdb kill-server
>
> sdb start-server
>
> sdb connect "YOURIPADDRESS"

Answer (score 0):

I spent two hours trying to connect the watch to the studio, in my case it helped me to turn off the debug in the watch and turn it back on, the studio immediately found the watch.